# MetaMask - RPC Error: The method "eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas" does not exist / is not available

Tags: metamask, hardhat

beginner here.

I understand that Hardhat does not support `eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas` anymore, which is why I am getting the following error:

`VM4452:1  MetaMask - RPC Error: The method "eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas" does not exist / is not available.  code :  -32601 data :  cause :  null origin :  "http://localhost:3000" [[Prototype]] :  Object message :  "The method \"eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas\" does not exist / is not available."`

And I am assuming my code is fine since I do get the MetaMask popup when calling my Solidity `purchase()` function, but the `confirm` button is disabled.

**MetaMask**

[image]

**JS Code**

```
const buyNFT = async (nft) => {
    try {
      const contract = await connectToContract();
      const price = ethers.parseUnits(nft.price, "ether");
      console.log(price);

      const transaction = await contract.purchase(nft.tokenId, {
        from: currentAccount,
        value: price,
        nonce: await provider.getTransactionCount(contractAddress, "latest"),
        gasLimit: 10000,
        gasPrice: parseInt((await provider.getFeeData()).gasPrice),
      });

      await transaction.wait();

      console.log(transaction);
      router.push("/author");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

**Solidity Code**

```
function purchase(uint256 _tokenId) public payable commissionRequired {
        if (MarketItems[_tokenId].price > msg.value) {
            revert InvalidPayment();
        }

        address payable seller = payable(MarketItems[_tokenId].seller);

        MarketItems[_tokenId].sold = true;
        MarketItems[_tokenId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
        MarketItems[_tokenId].seller = payable(address(0));

        tokensSold.increment();
        _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, _tokenId);

        (bool successCommission, ) = i_owner.call{value: commission}("");
        (bool successPay, ) = seller.call{value: msg.value}("");

        if (!successCommission) {
            revert MoneyTransferFailed();
        }
        if (!successPay) {
            revert MoneyTransferFailed();
        }
    }
```

So, my question simply is, what do I need to do to fix that error?